# How to do a map with negative values, midpoint equal to 0 and positive values using tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I'm currently working on creating a map using tm_polygons in R, and I'm specifically interested in implementing the Jenks classification for styling. My goal is to classify the values into three distinct ranges: strictly negative values, zero, and strictly positive values.

Here's a prototype of the classification and color scheme I'm aiming for:

-50 to -21 (red-type of color); -20 to -10 (red-type of color); -9 to -1 (red-type of color); 0 (white); 1 to 10 (blue-type of color); 10 to 30 (blue-type of color); 50 to 70 (blue-type of color)

I would appreciate any guidance or code snippets on how to achieve this classification using tm_polygons and ensuring the correct styling with the specified color ranges.

I have tried the following but without success:

```
tm_shape(df_name %>% filter(ANO == 2012), bbox = bbox_new) +
tm_polygons(col = "tot_reloc_net_05",
            style = "jenks" , palette = "RdBu", midpoint = 0, title = "", n = 5) + 
  tm_layout(main.title = "", 
            main.title.position = "center" ,frame = F, main.title.size = 1.5, fontfamily = "serif", fontface = "bold",
            legend.width = 0.40, legend.outside = F, legend.position = c(0.75, 0.25),legend.text.size = 0.5, legend.title.size = 1.0)+
  tm_shape(df_shape_1)+
  tm_borders(lwd = 1.85, col = "black")+
  tm_text("MA", xmod = -1.25, ymod = -0.995, size = 0.6) +
  tm_shape(df_shape_2)+
  tm_borders(lwd = 0.5, col = "black")+
  tm_compass(type = "arrow", position = c("right", "bottom"), size = 1.35)+
  tm_scale_bar(text.size = 0.45, position = c("right", "bottom"), width = 0.18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to debug it without your data, but I guess, the main issue is mixing the `jenks` style with desired classification. Please note, `jenks` style uses own bins for classification. Below examples of `jenks` and `fixed` styles classifications with same number of bins. Please note, I'm using newest version of {tmap} (you can install it from github) with `tmap::tm_scale_xxxxx()` functions, but (if I recall) in `tmap v.3` you can use `style` and `breaks` as parametrs for `tm_polygons()`.

```r
pl <- geodata::gadm("POL", level = 2, path = "/home/sapi/projekty/test/data") |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  sf::st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000)
pl$n <- sample(c(-50:50), nrow(pl), replace = TRUE)

tmap::tm_shape(pl) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "n",
                    fill.scale = tmap::tm_scale_intervals(
                      n = 8,
                      values = "RdBu",
                      style = "jenks",
                      midpoint = 0
                    ))
```

[image]

```r
tmap::tm_shape(pl) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(fill = "n",
                    fill.scale = tmap::tm_scale_intervals(
                      values = "RdBu",
                      style = "fixed",
                      breaks = c(-50, -30, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 30, 50),
                      midpoint = 0
                    ))
```

[image]

```r
packageVersion("tmap")
#> [1] '3.99.9000'
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-03 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. Is it possible to "isolate" the midpoint = 0 as it is possible with "NA" values? I know it is possible to set, for instance, colorNA = "white" and textNA = "Missing". Is it possible to do something similar to "0" or will I need to set zero values as missing?

Comment: I don't believe you can isolate 0 in easy way. All intervals are closed from one side, either left, either right. So the breaks are `50 >= x > 30`, `30 >= x > 10`, etc. And 0 will be part of left/right interval as well. Your solution with `NA` might be the best option. Please have a look `?classInt::classify_intervals()`.